# Events and Full Calendar in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, fullcalendar

I set the FullCalendar plugin in CakePHP, i can see it, it's displayed, i'm trying to put the events from my PHP Controller (the view admin feed) to my Full Calendar Plugin . I don't know what's wrong , no events are displayed in my calendar . I will be thankfull if someone can find why my calandar is empty . 
Look the screen, this is what i have in my console :

[image]

The answer is NULL .

The JS file :

```
// JavaScript Document

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                firstHour: 8,
                weekMode: 'variable',
                aspectRatio: 2,
                editable: true,
            events: {
                url: FcRoot + '/events/feed',
                color: 'yellow',    // an option!
                textColor: 'black',  // an option!
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
            ///
            }
        });

    });
```

EventsController

```
// The feed action is called from JS to get the list of events (JSON)
    public function admin_feed($id=null) {
        $this->layout = "ajax";
        $vars = $this->params['url'];
        $conditions = array('conditions' => array('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) >=' => $vars['start'], 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) <=' => $vars['end']));
        $events = $this->Event->find('all', $conditions);
        foreach($events as $event) {
            if($event['Event']['all_day'] == 1) {
                $allday = true;
                $end = $event['Event']['start'];
            } else {
                $allday = false;
                $end = $event['Event']['end'];
            }
            $data[] = array(
                    'id' => $event['Event']['id'],
                    'title'=>$event['Event']['title'],
                    'start'=>$event['Event']['start'],
                    'end' => $end
            );
        }
        $this->set("json", json_encode($data));
    }
```

In View/Events/admin_feed

```
<?php 
echo $json; 
?>
```

The response now :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really take advantage of routing and views for this. It allows you to properly organize your code and keep things DRY.

```
 public function admin_feed($id=null) {
    $vars = $this->params['url'];
    $conditions = array('conditions' => array('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) >=' => $vars['start'], 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) <=' => $vars['end']));
    $events = $this->Event->find('all', $conditions);
    foreach($events as $event) {
        if($event['Event']['all_day'] == 1) {
            $allday = true;
            $end = $event['Event']['start'];
        } else {
            $allday = false;
            $end = $event['Event']['end'];
        }
        $data[] = array(
                'id' => $event['Event']['id'],
                'title'=>$event['Event']['title'],
                'start'=>$event['Event']['start'],
                'end' => $end
        );
    }
    $this->set("events", $data);
}
```

Now, your `admin_feed` action is usable as more than just a json feed (even though that may be just want you want). This makes testing easier as well.

Add the following to your routes, to tell Cake that you want to allow the `json` extension:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Then, add the `RequestHandler` to your controller components. This component will automatically switch to your json view and layout when a json extension is found.

Next, add a layout for all json views in `/View/Layout/json/default.ctp`:

```
<?php
echo $this->fetch('content');
```

Then, add your view in `/View/Events/json/admin_feed.ctp`:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($events);
```

That's it. Now, if you want to use `admin_feed` to view events in HTML, you can by adding a view for it.

Your full calendar url should now be: `FcRoot + '/admin/events/feed.json'`. Try just visiting it in the browser to see if you see the json.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i did exactly what you wrote, when i'm going to http://127.0.0.1/NOUVEAU/admin/events/feed.json , it's writen "null" . I have my table events, some other views , there are data inside . I don't understand why . :/

Comment: i added a new screen ^^ From the console, the response i get is the html code for the page, the layout i guess ...

Comment: When you visit in the browser do you get json? json and HTML? If an error is happening in the page, the json will be malformed. Or if you're including debug info it can cause a problem with the json as well. Check it in the browser first to see if you're getting errors or debug info.

Comment: In the browser, if i type the url, i'm getting "null" . If i'm going to the page (the view where the fullcalendar is) the events are not displayed and in my console (firebug), i have a HTML code in response . I put the screen in my first post .

Comment: Try debugging `$events` in the view, then. It sounds like `json_encode` is failing.

Comment: in admin_feed ? debug($events); ? Do i have to delete the json_encode for debugging ?

Comment: You don't have to delete anything to debug. If you're in the function `admin_feed`, `debug($data);` since you named the variable data. In the view, it's named `$events` which you could change to data if you wanted to. They're events, so I named them events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58012/discussion-between-jeremyharris-and-user3790914).

Answer (score 1):

do not set it, just echo it

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

set values are supposed to be used in view, in your case you are just 'returning' as ajax response

for ajax calls, view is not necessary at all, put `$this->autoRender = false;` in you function: this will prevent 'seeking' for view file.

Comment: I edited my post, i have a view with a json echo . I tried to put "echo json_encode($data);" instead of echo $json but it's sill the same .

Comment: @user3790914 I updated the answer, pls give it a try, if it does not work, use debug to see the output: instead of `echo json_encode($data);` try `debug($data);die;` in your function before json_encode and look at firebug, if it is empty, it means the problem is with your `$data`. P.S. debug is just for development, ASA u understand the problem, get back to echo json_encode of course.

Comment: This is not recommended because it makes it very difficult to test, and breaks common patterns which makes understanding the code more difficult. Don't be lazy, make a view :)

Comment: @jeremyharris what is the difficulty with testing ? it is not about laziness, why to render into view, that there is no need ? if you should use view, then you should set in controller and then use it in view, extra more step... + the rendering process, but preventing rendering those 2 steps are gone

Comment: @hashmode by testing, I mean unit testing. `echo`ing requires you to capture the buffer to make sure you get the expected result. The extra step separates the concerns, and makes it easier to pick out where errors lie. The render process doesn't take much time or effort. Saving steps, like skipping unit testing because it saves time, often seems like a good idea but usually turns out to make things more difficult down the road.

Comment: @hashmode another reason to do it "properly" is if you ever want to reuse this action. Reusable code is always a win.